# Spark job failing with "Fail to know the executor driver is alive or not", "Cannot find endpoint: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@<host:port>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a job on a local Spark cluster (pyspark). When I run it with a small dataset it works fine, but once it's large, I get an error. I'm wondering 1. How to find logs from the scheduler process that appears to be crashing, and 2. more generally, what might be going on and how to debug the problem. Thanks in advance. Happy to provide more info.

Here's the error (from what I understand to be the driver logs):

```
block-manager-ask-thread-pool-224 ERROR BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Fail to know th
e executor driver is alive or not.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at...
    ...
    <stacktrace>
    ...

Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointNotFoundException: Cannot find endpoint: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@<host:port>
```

and then immediately below that

```
block-manager-ask-thread-pool-224 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Error trying to remove shuffle 25. The executor driver may have been lost.
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply from <host:port>
```

What I know about my job... I'm using Pyspark and running Spark standalone, using a local cluster with 72 workers (the machine has 96 cores). Here's my config:

```
spark:
  master: "local[72]"
  files:
    maxPartitionBytes: 67108864
  sql:
    files:
      maxPartitionBytes: 67108864
  driver:
    memory: "50g"
    maxResultSize: "2g"
    supervise: true
    cores: 72
    log:
      dfsDir: <my/logs/dir>
      persistToDfs:
        enabled: true
  loglevel: "WARN"
  logConf: true
```

I've set `SPARK_LOG_DIR` and `SPARK_WORKER_LOG_DIR` to attempt to see scheduler logs, but I still only see driver (worker?) logs as far as I can tell, with the above error. I'm monitoring memory usage and it doesn't *seem* like my machine is memory-constrained, but I can't be sure I'm checking at the right moments. The machine has about 1TB of memory and tens of terabytes of free disk space.

Thanks in advance!